# i cant map usestate from AppContexet.Consumer

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

i send a usestate thro AppContexet.Provider to AppContexet.Consumer,
i can see at the components - the data arived but when i tray to map the state i get an erorr.
what m i doing wrong?

this is the perent :

```
import {useState} from 'react'
import Ex53Child from './Ex53Child'
import AppContexet from './Appcontext'
import React, {Component} from 'react';


const Ex53perent = ()=>
{
   const [name,setName] = useState('')
   const [age,setAge] = useState()
   const [users,setUsers] = useState ([])
   const [user,setUser] = useState ({name : '' , age : ''})


   
    return(<AppContexet.Provider value = {{...users}}>
    <div>
        
       <h1> Ex53perent comp </h1>
       Name: <input type = "text" onChange = {e=>setUser({...user ,name : e.target.value})}/><br/>
       Age : <input type = "text" onChange = {e=>setUser({...user ,age : e.target.value})}/><br/>
       <input type = "button" value ="Add" onClick ={e=>setUsers([...users,user])}/>
       <Ex53Child/>
      
      
      
        </div>
        </AppContexet.Provider>
        )
}
export default Ex53perent;
```

---

this is the child :

```
import {useState} from 'react'
import AppContexet from './Appcontext'
import Ex53GrenChild from './Ex53GrenChild'



const Ex53Child = ()=>
{
   
const [myUesr,setMyUser] = useState([])
   
    return(<AppContexet.Consumer>

        {
            dataContext =>
            (
                <div>
                    <h1> Ex53Child comp </h1>
                    
                    {
                        dataContext.users.map((item,index)=>
                        {
                            return<il key = {index}>
                                <li>{item.name}</li>
                                <li>{item.age}</li>
                            </il>
                        })
                    }
                    

                    <Ex53GrenChild/>
                
                </div>
            )
        }
        
        </AppContexet.Consumer>
        )
}
export default Ex53Child;
```

and this is the appcontext file:

```
import React from 'react'

const AppContexet = React.createContext();

export default AppContexet;
```

a singel value work just fine
but i cant map the arry from some resen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

The `users` state is an array:

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
```

And you are spreading the array into an object:

```
<AppContexet.Provider value={{ ...users }}>
  ...
</AppContexet.Provider>
```

This makes the context value an object where the array indices are now object keys and the array values are object values.

## Solutions

### Convert context value to array

You *could* keep it this way, and then you'll need to convert the context value back to an array in the child:

```
<AppContexet.Consumer>
  {dataContext => (
    <div>
      <h1>Ex53Child comp</h1>
      {Object.values(dataContext).map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <il key={index}>
              <li>{item.name}</li>
              <li>{item.age}</li>
            </il>
          );
        })
      }
      <Ex53GrenChild/>
    </div>
  )}
</AppContexet.Consumer>
```

### Fix context value, keep it an array

It's better to just keep the `users` and context values consistently an array. Don't spread the `users` state into the context value.

```
<AppContexet.Provider value={{ users }}>
  ...
</AppContexet.Provider>
```

Now's the context value is an object with a single `users` property that is the `users` state.

```
<AppContexet.Consumer>
  {dataContext => (
    <div>
      <h1>Ex53Child comp</h1>
      {dataContext.users.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <il key={index}>
              <li>{item.name}</li>
              <li>{item.age}</li>
            </il>
          );
        })
      }
      <Ex53GrenChild/>
    </div>
  )}
</AppContexet.Consumer>
```

#### Use `useContext` hook

Since `Ex53Child` is a function component it's a bit silly to use the `AppContexet.Consumer` component render function. Use the `useContext` hook instead.

```
const Ex53Child = () => {
  const [myUesr, setMyUser] = useState([]);
  const { users } = useContext(AppContexet);
   
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Ex53Child comp</h1>
      {users.map((item, index) => (
        <il key={index}>
          <li>{item.name}</li>
          <li>{item.age}</li>
        </il>
      ))}
      <Ex53GrenChild />
    </div>
  );
}
```

#### Just pass `users` as a prop

Additionally, since `Ex53perent` is directly rendering `Ex53Child`, using the context is unnecessary complexity when the `users` state could just simply be passed as a prop.

```
const Ex53perent = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [age, setAge] = useState();
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [user, setUser] = useState({ name: '', age: '' });
   
  return (
    <div>
      <h1> Ex53perent comp </h1>
      Name:{" "}
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={e => setUser({ ...user, name: e.target.value })}
      />
      <br/>
      Age:{" "}
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={e => setUser({ ...user, age: e.target.value })}
      />
      <br/>
      <input
        type="button"
        value="Add"
        onClick={e => setUsers([...users, user])}
      />
      <Ex53Child users={users} /> // <-- pass users as prop to child
    </div>
  );
};
```

...

```
const Ex53Child = ({ users }) => { // <-- access users from props
  const [myUesr, setMyUser] = useState([]);
   
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Ex53Child comp</h1>
      {users.map((item, index) => (
        <il key={index}>
          <li>{item.name}</li>
          <li>{item.age}</li>
        </il>
      ))}
      <Ex53GrenChild />
    </div>
  );
}
```